# How to evaluate a prefix expression with stacks using linked lists, in scala

Tags: scala, recursion, linked-list, stack

I need help with this code, to do the differents methods, like top, pop, push using the linkedlist. Also with the logic of how to evaluate the expression in prefix recursively, since I don't know if it's right or wrong.

For example a user put "+56" and with the stack resolve this and out 11.

I tried with this code.

```
seaed trait LinkedList[+A]
case object Nil extends LinkedList[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head:A,tail:LinkedList[A]) extends LinkedList[A]

object LinkedList
{

  def apply[A](ll:A*): LinkedList[A] = 
  {
    if(ll.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(ll.head, apply(ll.tail:_*))
  }


  // añadir a la cabeza
  def preppend[A](ll: LinkedList[A], new_element:A): LinkedList[A] = ll match //pattern matching
  {
    case Nil => LinkedList(new_element)
    case Cons(x,xs) => Cons(new_element, Cons(x,xs))
  }


  def pop[A](ll: LinkedList[A]): A = ll match
  {
    case Cons(h, t) => 
      {
        val value = h
        ll = t
        return value
      }
  }


  def eval(string: String): Int =
  {

    var stack = LinkedList()
    var result = 0

    def go(string: String, stack: LinkedList[Char]): Int =
    {

      if (string.isEmpty) return result

      if (string.charAt(0).equals('+') || string.charAt(0).equals('-') || string.charAt(0).equals('*') || string.charAt(0).equals('/'))
        {
          var left_value = pop(stack)
          var right_value = pop(stack)

          if (string.charAt(0).equals('+'))
          {
            result = (left_value + right_value)
          }
    
          if (string.charAt(0).equals('-'))
          {
            result = (left_value - right_value)
          }
    
          if (string.charAt(0).equals('*'))
          {
            result = (left_value * right_value)
          }
    
          else
          {
            result = (left_value / right_value)
          }
          return go(string.substring(1), stack)
        }

      else
      {
        preppend(stack, string.charAt(0).toInt-'0')
        return go(string.substring(1), stack)
      }
    }

    go(string, stack)

  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    LinkedList.eval("-45")
  }

}
```

Comment: I suggest removing `eval` from `LinkedList` and implementing it using the built-in `List` class e.g. `def eval(s: String): List[Char]`.  You can then implement `LinkedList` as a separate task.

Comment: Your code has too many problems which makes it impossible to understand your requirement. Can you give your exact requirement with examples of what the program is supposed to do with inputs ?

Comment: @sarveshseri, its made like a calculator of prefix expressions with stacks using linked list,  for example a user put "/*344", and out 3

Comment: So... you don't need a generic `LinkedList[A]`... it can just use concrete `Double`.

Comment: Does it need to be implemented using stack ?